# $f \in L_1([0,1],m)$ such that $\int_0^1 f \sin (n^2x) \ dm= 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have the space of $\mathbb{K}$-valued integrable functions with respect to a Lebesgue measure $m$ and I need to find a function $f$ such that $\int_0^1 |f| \ dm=1$ and $\int_0^1 f  \sin(n^2x) \ dm=1 $, $n \geq 2, n \in \mathbb{N}$. I was thinking to take a continuous function so it's Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ and then I can "forget" the Lebesgue measure, but I don't know if it's a good idea.

Comment: What is $\mathbb K$?

Comment: What is the purpose of the cancelling $n$s? It looks like you want a function satisfying $\int_0^1 f(x) \sin(n^2 x) \, dm(x) = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: A field, can be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: No, that integral should be $n$, not $1$

Comment: What is the $n$ in between $f$ and $\sin$ in the integral then?

Comment: It's any natural number greater than $2$

Comment: That's not what I meant. You have a factor of $n$ on both sides of the equation. They cancel to give you $\int_0^1 f(x) \sin(n^2 x) \, dm(x) = 1$.

Comment: Oh yes, I got what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You won't find such a function.

If $f \in L^1[0,1]$ the *Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma* tells you that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x) \sin(nx) \, dx = 0.$$

Comment: So, how can I show part $a)$ of this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035444/bounded-linear-maps-and-lebesgue-integral/3035506#3035506

Comment: Comments aren't the place for new questions; perhaps you should post that as a question.